# Cohort Analysis by month - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to do a cohort analysis for the year 2017. I have the following two tables

1. FirstPurchases - Where I determine the first purchase a client has made that is greater than 1. The reason for this is that we have credit card verification purchases that is less than 1 usd upon first transaction.
2. Transaction - this is the table that records all purchasing and refund transactions by customers.

The sql that I have written is the following

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FirstPurchases`;
CREATE TABLE `FirstPurchases`
(
SELECT account_id,MIN(created_date) AS transaction_date
FROM `transaction`
WHERE transaction.amount > 1
GROUP BY  account_id
);

DELETE FROM `FirstPurchases`
WHERE YEAR(transaction_date) = 2016;


SELECT u.MonthOffset AS MONTH,

  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 0) AS d0,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 1) AS d1,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 2) AS d2,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 3) AS d3,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 4) AS d4,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 5) AS d5,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 6) AS d6,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 7) AS d7,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 8) AS d8,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 9) AS d9,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 10) AS d10,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 11) AS d11,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 12) AS d12 
FROM (
 SELECT
    account_id,
    MONTH(transaction_date) AS MonthOffset
  FROM `FirstPurchases`
  WHERE transaction_date >= CURDATE() - DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),'2017-01-01')
) AS u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    transaction.account_id,
    PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(transaction.created_date,'%Y%m'),DATE_FORMAT(FirstPurchases.transaction_date,'%Y%m')) AS MonthOffset
    FROM `transaction`
    LEFT JOIN `FirstPurchases`  ON (transaction.account_id = `FirstPurchases`.account_id)
    WHERE `transaction`.created_date >= CURDATE() - DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),'2017-01-01')
) AS s
ON s.account_id = u.account_id
GROUP BY u.MonthOffset;
```

although I am confident that d0 is correct. The rest of the numbers feel inflated to me. I have gone through this exercise manually and the figures dont match up. Can anyone maybe cast an eye and see where I went wrong ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: we'd need to see sample data and expected output as well, otherwise the query by itself is a bit meaningless and abstract. You can't prove the correctness of something without knowing the possible parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I am a bit of a dumbass and the query is correct. I forgot to filter out refunds in my left join. So if anyone wants to use this as a template for cohort analysis there u go :)